# Multiple drop zones in AG Grid not working

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to create multiple tables that i can drag and drop rows from and to. But whenever I have more than two tables, dragging a row over the third table gives an error.
Demo can be checked here: [plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/o5agxAvDBbUKMPk1?open=index.jsx&preview)

Here's the code trying to set two dropzones to a GridApi:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (rightApi && leftApi && midApi) {
    const leftDropZone = leftApi.getRowDropZoneParams();
    const rightDropZone = rightApi.getRowDropZoneParams();
    const midDropZone = midApi.getRowDropZoneParams();

    rightApi.addRowDropZone(leftDropZone);
    rightApi.addRowDropZone(midDropZone);

    leftApi.addRowDropZone(rightDropZone);
    leftApi.addRowDropZone(midDropZone);

    midApi.addRowDropZone(rightDropZone);
    midApi.addRowDropZone(leftDropZone);
  }
}, [midApi, leftApi, rightApi]);
```

I have tried recreating the problem on their own drag and drop example given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging-to-grid/)
It has been stripped down to only include parts relevant to the issue, and another grid has been added to showcase the issue.